# Is it possible to switch from condensed matter theory PhD to high energy theory in postdoc work?

Tags: phd, research-process, physics

Suppose that my PhD work is on CMT, very field theoretic in techniques. Then, is it possible to work on hep-ph and hep-th areas in postdoc? Is it a lot harder than the opposite way or other people who have PhD in high energy theory? Do you know any examples of success?

Comment: If you find a PI who takes you on, you can pretty much do whatever you want as a postdoc. That's the whole idea. Some paths are easier and some are harder, but what counts in the end is what you are interested in.

Comment: Expanding on @Gerhard's comment: what specific skills and knowledge do you have that would make you more valuable than specialist candidates in the field applying for the same position?

Comment: Also, what are your motivations in making the change? Do you plan to be a high-energy theorist in the future? Or work on both topics? Or stay in CMT but just want to develop some other skills during postdoc?

Comment: Hans Bethe is arguable an example (a high-profile one at that) but I've struggled to think of more recent ones.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the off-topic question, but I'm also planning to join a PhD in condmat, but I'm trying to find a position which involves field theoretic techniques. I haven't found many professors from visiting University websites. Can you suggest or recommend any people since you'd have been active in the field for quite some time?